# PHP - Sum array by defined condition of value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, sum

Please I need help to summarize a values of array by some conditions

i have this result query :
[image: result of query]

I want to calcul the Sum of calls for each user, i try with like this, but its show me the sum of all query [Users]

```
$array_out_ = array();
$usercalls =  $usertalk =  $userpause =  $userwait = $userdispo = $userdead = 0;
    foreach ($queryusers2 as $user) {
            $current_user = $user['user'];
            $usercalls += $user['calls'];
            $usertalk += $user['talk'];
            $userpause += $user['pause'];
            $userwait += $user['wait'];
            $userdispo += $user['dispo'];
            $userdead += $user['dead'];

        $array_out_[$current_user]['calls'] = $usercalls;
        $array_out_[$current_user]['talk'] = $usertalk;
        $array_out_[$current_user]['pause'] = $userpause;
        $array_out_[$current_user]['wait'] = $userwait;
        $array_out_[$current_user]['dispo'] = $userdispo;
        $array_out_[$current_user]['dead'] = $userdead;
    }
```

This method return me $usercalls (305 for agent29 ) and (436 for agent117)
But i want 305 ofr agent 29 and only 131 for the agent117

Thanks

Comment: Do it in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values `$usercalls`,`$usertalk`,... are not re-initialized. and are cumulated for all users. Your code works **only for the first user** and only because your list is ordered by users.

You could initialize an array and sum directly inside it:

```
$array_out_ = array();

foreach ($queryusers2 as $user)
{
    $current_user = $user['user'];

    if (!isset($array_out_[$current_user])) {
        $array_out_[$current_user] = [
            'calls' => 0, 'talk' => 0, 'pause' => 0, 'wait' => 0,
            'dispo' => 0, 'dead' => 0
        ];
    }

    $array_out_[$current_user]['calls'] += $user['calls'];
    $array_out_[$current_user]['talk'] += $user['talk'];
    $array_out_[$current_user]['pause'] += $user['pause'];
    $array_out_[$current_user]['wait'] += $user['wait'];
    $array_out_[$current_user]['dispo'] += $user['dispo'];
    $array_out_[$current_user]['dead'] += $user['dead'];
}
```

---

See also [the answer of Enric Borrallo Rodriguez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49537735/php-sum-array-by-defined-condition-of-value/49538075#49538075)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you change the query SQL to something like this, where you can  group and sum your data.

```
SELECT
   tn.user,
   SUM(tn.calls) AS usercalls,
   SUM(tn.talk) AS usertalk,
   SUM(tn.pause) AS userpause,
   SUM(tn.wait) AS userwait,
   SUM(tn.dispo) AS userdispo,
   SUM(tn.dead) AS userdead
FROM tablename tn
GROUP BY tn.user
```

And this will return what you need:

```
agent29,  305, ...

agent117, 436, ...
```

Comment: I agree it would be good to do this in the database if possible.

Comment: This is a better answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to your answer, for future users.

Comment: Yes , it's better, I already have this solution in mind but i couldn' use it because i have a group by 3 elements (User, UserGroup, Status) .. Thnx